# Load generating on server using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have a requirement to do load test on an API (which is having response as a json .No UI and etc).

What is the best component to use to test with 100 users or more .Which thread group is best to use .

If someone has any examples please share alongwith screenshots here.

Comment: Not sure, but is it http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/restAPIJMeter.html what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for sharing url @Mr.log_file , right now I was following the same way but I my requests are getting failed with more than 25 users.So I felt there is some alternative approach.

Comment: Try increasing number of users and RampUp i.e. Number of users = 100 and RampUp = 5. Try with this configuration and see if it works.

Comment: @Dhiman : if I configure Rampup time then the response time will increase ? bcoz it will wait for the 5 sec for every new user/thread right ?

Comment: No, your response time will not increase. Rampup time is not added in Response Time, but yes if you have used Timers in your script, then it might get added to Response Time depending upon the configuration you have selected. So you can increase RampUp without any issue.

Comment: thanks @Dhiman , I  tried with adding ramp up period but now I am getting as a 504-gateway time out error

Comment: Can you provide the JMeter logs and more information that what you are trying to do in your script?

Answer (score 2):

I hope you not using JMeter in GUI mode. If you do - please switch to [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) as JMeter GUI is very resource intensive and may ruin your test.

The same for the [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners): if you have View Results Tree or View Results in Table listeners added and enabled - remove or disable them as they consume a lot of CPU and RAM.

Follow recommendations from [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://JMeter%20Performance%20and%20Tuning%20Tips) guide - this way you will be able to simulate much more than 100 virtual users.

Another piece of advice: if you going to do some testing on REST API - it's likely that you'll have to deal with JSON data. Vanilla JMeter's JSON support is not so good so I recommend using the following test elements:

- [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) - to perform correlation if needed
- [JSON Path Assertion](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathAssertion/) - to conditionally set pass/fail criteria

Both are available via "Extras with Libs" set of the [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) project.